# Elastic search queries with Java api

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch

How can I return only matching objects now with my code when finds one matching with the value returns the whole nested object back?

```
  private def queryBuilder(
      field: String,
      value: String,
      parent: Option[String] = None
  ): BoolQueryBuilder = {
    val boolQuery: BoolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    parent match {
      case Some(parentName) =>
        boolQuery.filter(
          QueryBuilders
            .nestedQuery(
              parentName,
              QueryBuilders
                .boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(field, value)),
              ScoreMode.None
            )
        )
      case None => boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(field, value))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to return only matching nested document you can add [`inner_hit`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) to the nested query.

For e.g.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "nested_field",
      "query": {
        "match": { "nested_field.field1": "value_to_match" }
      },
      "inner_hits": {} 
    }
  }
}
```

In response you'll find `inner_hits` section which only contains the matching nested document.